# autocomplete in angular with typehead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I tried to do an autocomplete in angular with typehead, but it is not working.

I downloaded the typehead.js from angularstrap page.

**javascript:**

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'myservice', function ($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.name= [];
    myservice.getData().then(function (msg) {
        $scope.name= msg.data.names;
    });

    $scope.input = "";

}]);
```

**html:**

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input" 
      bs-options="name for name in names" bs-typeahead>

 </div>
```

What have I done wrong?

If there is a better solution for autocomplete example pls tell me.
thx in advance

Comment: Please debug your code first, before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$scope.name` should be `$scope.names` if you want it to work with the expression you are using in `bs-options`. Eg

#### Javascript:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'myservice', function ($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.names= [];
    myservice.getData().then(function (msg) {
        $scope.names= msg.data.names;
    });

    $scope.input = "";

}]);
```

I've created an [example plunker to show your code working](http://plnkr.co/edit/IwvFz2EHbsI7BBoxGqwH?p=preview) with the fix above.

Comment: yes i Know. I typed it wrong I have in my code "$scope.names" but it is still not working.

Comment: I've added a working example. For future reference, it's important to add as much detail as you can including actual code, error messages, steps to reproduce etc. This will give you better answers and people more likely to help you.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was, that i just added the "angular.js" file and the typehead form https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js. But this was not enough. You also added other files, which was for autocomplete feature required.