# Input: autocomplete with angularstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know I asked two days ago the same question :(
[autocomplete in angular with typehead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164935/autocomplete-in-angular-with-typehead)

When I  just copied the example from the plunker it worked well. But know i installed the whole angular-strap  and wanted to bind my own sources so now it is not working.

```
<div data-ng-controller="ConnectionController">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedState" 
 bs-options="state for state in states" placeholder="Enter state" bs-typeahead>
</div>
```

my app:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize','mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

the scripts i bound in _layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
```

No i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24sanitizeUriPr…%24sceDelegate%20%3C-%20%24sce%20%3C-%20%24interpolate%20%3C-%20%24compile(anonymous function) @ MINERR_ASSET:22(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3444c @ angular.js:3571(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3449c @ angular.js:3571d @ angular.js:3593(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3450c @ angular.js:3571$get @ angular.js:12061d @ angular.js:3617(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3450c @ angular.js:3571d @ angular.js:3593(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3450c @ angular.js:3571d @ angular.js:3593(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3450c @ angular.js:3571d @ angular.js:3593(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3450c @ angular.js:3571d @ angular.js:3593Wb.c @ angular.js:1283Wb @ angular.js:1297Oc @ angular.js:1246(anonymous function) @ angular.js:20026a @ angular.js:2291(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2555q @ angular.js:300Uc.c @ angular.js:2554
```

angular.js:78

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$sanitizeUriProvider <-         $$sanitizeUri <- $sanitize <- $sceDelegate <- $sce <- $interpolate <- $compile
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24sanitizeUriProvid…%24sceDelegate%20%3C-%20%24sce%20%3C-%20%24interpolate%20%3C-%20%24compile

Comment: could you please confirm `angular.js` & `angular-sanitize.js` versions are same?

Comment: ok the versions are not same. I installed it from nuget-paket-manager in visual studio. I have got older ones.

Comment: So make them of same versions..

Comment: still not working. I get many errors

Comment: I just tried to load the modules and I got errors. So basically the module loading is not working fine

Comment: ok. it´s working now. the angular.js version was not compatible. I just copied the angular.min.js thx for help

Comment: should I add an answer?

Comment: then please you should add an answer..as it may help other who are facing these issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the wrong versions of angular.js. I had an very old version, so that´s why it did not work.